# Why is my facebook app profile box not updated after I change it on my server?

Tags: facebook, caching

I just recently started to  develop facebook apps, so heres my simple question:

My app displays a profile box, but whenever I update the file on my server, facebook still displays the old version.

How can I make facebook use the "new" code?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 1):

The profile box shown on Facebook is a cached version, Facebook doesn't hit your server when the box is displayed. If you want to update the profile box contents, you have to post new content to Facebook so the cache will be updated.
Use the profile_setFBML function. You don't need a session handle if you provide a user ID.